# Dynamically set a XML tag value while building payload

Tags: testing, automation, karate

I am trying automate testing using Karate.

I have a XML payload.

I have a static XML payload which I am readying from a file and I want to call my service in loop.

For each call I would like to replace value for a tag name dynamically.

How would I achieve this?

e.g.

Below is my Main Feature which calls my common feature in loop

```
Feature: Loop Call
Background:
* def common = call read('classpath:CommonFeatures.feature')

Scenario:
* table table
    | payload_file    | field_tag  | field_value |
    | 'HappyPath.xml' | 'car_fuel' | 'Gas'     |
    | 'HappyPath.xml' | 'car_color'| 'Red'     |

* def response = call read('classpath:Car.feature')  table
```

Car.feature

```
Feature: Common
Scenario:
    * print payload_file
    * print field_tag
    * print field_value
    * xml payload = read('classpath:/payload/'+payload_file)
    * print payload
    * set payload/$field_tag = field_value
```

This is where I have issue setting the field_tag value.

I have other option to do this like writing a small java script method to replace the tag value or a small java class which use DOMParser or SAXParser to perform the same.

However I would like to know if there is any karate in build way to perform the same.

Also while using java script method to replace the tag value if I am using var parser = new DOMParser(); and it seems DOMParser is not available to use. Is there a way to make this available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Peter for all help and the examples.

I feel this is the best way to achieve this.

Wrote a small javascript function

```
   """
    * def replaceTag =
      """
      function(x){
        karate.setXml('temp', x.payload);
        karate.pretty(karate.get('temp'));
        if (x.field_tag) karate.set('temp', x.field_tag, x.field_value);
        return karate.get('temp');
      }
    """
```

and calling the same from Car.feature like below and I get the dynamically replaced payload.

```
Feature: Common
Scenario:
    * print payload_file
    * print field_tag
    * print field_value
    * xml payload = read('classpath:/payload/'+payload_file)
    * print payload
    * def args = { payload: #(payload), field_tag: #(field_tag), field_value: #
          (field_value)}
    * print args
    * xml payload = call common.replaceTag args
```

Note: I had to upgrade Karate 0.7.0 version in order to use karate.setXml method.

Comment: glad that this works for you. I am not sure that this is the best solution, maybe a string replace would have been more than enough, but hey :)

Comment: and can you mark your own answer as "accepted" it improves overall ratings on Stack Overflow, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I thought of using string replace. In my case I am using the same payload for happy path and also want to use for negative test cases just replacing certain tag values. Hence wanted to dynamically replace certain tag and values and expect the error code response.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you go through this sample, it will answer all your questions: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/b329d50e0042e76b20544138bf3fb31a79892f90/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

For example this is how you can substitute values, as well replace a whole chunk of XML (which can include tags) using the `set` keyword:

```
Scenario: set xml chunks using xpath
    * def req = read('envelope1.xml')
    * def phone = '123456'
    * def search = 
    """
    <acc:getAccountByPhoneNumber>
        <acc:phoneNumber>#(phone)</acc:phoneNumber>
    </acc:getAccountByPhoneNumber>
    """
    * set req /Envelope/Body = search
    * match req ==
    """
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://foo/bar">
        <soapenv:Header />
        <soapenv:Body>
            <acc:getAccountByPhoneNumber>
                <acc:phoneNumber>123456</acc:phoneNumber>
            </acc:getAccountByPhoneNumber>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    """
```

And please don't think of using DOMParser etc, you will be able to do anything you need via Karate syntax.

Comment: Perfect Thanks. I will add the solution as an answer