Unable to update same XML field for multiple occurrences
I can set the value of an xml field using - * set inputXML /Envelope/Body/createData/item[name='Effective Date'][2]/values/item =  newValue // This correctly setting the second occurrence.
Note - we can have single or multiple tags with name Effective Date.
Now I want to update all the fields dynamically present for tag 'Effective Date'.
I was trying to create a generic function to achieve it.
Function to achieve it :
* def setMultipleValues =
  """
  function(xml, path, newValue) {
  var items = karate.xmlPath(xml, path);
  
  xmlString = karate.prettyXml(xml);
  karate.log('Length: ', items.length); //It is correctly printing length
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var itemPath = path + '[' + (i + 1) + ']' + "/values/item";
    karate.log('setting value at: ', itemPath);
    try {
        karate.set(xmlString, itemPath, activitydate) ;
    } catch (e) {
        karate.log('Error setting value at: ', itemPath, ' with error: ', e);
    }
  }
  return xmlString;
  }

  """

Calling the function to set the values like below:
* eval inputXML = setMultipleValues (inputXML, path, newvalue)

It is failing with:
error:kaaret.set()java.lang.RuntimeException: variable is null or not set


sorry, this is too complicated and lacks information - so I pass. see if this other answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040188/143475 - please read this and try to edit+improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
